# Регистр букв в названии класса

Tags: php

```
class Boot {

}
```

можно ли обращаться к классу с маленькой буквы?

```
new boot()
```

Comment: Млин, ну самому ж проверить быстрее, чем писать вопрос сюда)))

Зная РНР скорее всего - да, на регистр класса ему положить также, как на регистр функций.

Answer (score 6):

Вообще то не стоит, как был оглавлен класс, так, будьте добры, и вызывайте.

Comment: Эх, полностью согласен:
"Как корабль назовешь, так он и поплывет" :)

Answer (score 4):

Обратиться можно, но есть нюанс. Если используется автоподгрузка классов, то `autoloader` получит то, что вы напишете в том же регистре. И под unix-системой файл `boat.php` может отсутствовать.